# Big delay between getting data and setting it as UILabel Text

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ipad

I get currency rate using this code.

```
let USDAUD = NSURL(string: "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=USDAUD=X&f=nl1d1t1")

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(USDAUD!) {(data, response, error) in
        println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
        if let string = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
            let exchangeRate = string.componentsSeparatedByString(",")[1].doubleValue
            self.displayValue.text = "\(exchangeRate)"
        }
    }

    task.resume()
```

But delay between getting data and setting as a label text is too high. What should i do?

Comment: with NSURLSession.sharedSession() it should be fine, is your cvs size too big?

Comment: Look up "UI updates must be done on the main thread" – There must be many similar question with that answer ...

Comment: @ÖzgürErsil no, if i output data in console it's ok.